# é replaced by e? on windows Java

Tags: java, io, copy, character, directory

So I am making a Java app/program that makes backup of a specific folder (name of folder is really long but it starts with "Pok**é**mon"), my problem is that this folder contains an accent (this one é). I have a mac, when I run the program, it runs fine, but whenever I try it on Windows, my program searches for a folder and instead of "é", I see a "e?" (in the console, when I print the string of the path, I get this Poke?mon). Is it a problem with Windows formatting? How could I solve this?

```
void SaveNow (String folderName) {
    String fullOriginalPath = getMCPath() + "saves/Pokémon Cobalt and Amethyst [DEMO]";
    String fullNewPath = getMCPath() + "PokeCA/" + folderName;
    System.out.println("Path to original PokeCA map: " + fullOriginalPath); //At this point, the é is replaced by e?
    System.out.println("Path to backup PokeCA map: " + fullNewPath);

    if (OsUtils.isWindows()) {
        fullOriginalPath = MakeWinPath(fullOriginalPath); //Replaces all / by \ because Windows
        fullNewPath = MakeWinPath(fullNewPath); //Same
    }

    File source = new File(fullOriginalPath);
    File dest = new File(fullNewPath);

    try {
        FileUtils.copyDirectory(source, dest);
        System.out.println("Successfully backuped map!");
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frmSave, "Successfully backuped map!");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frmSave, "Error, could not backup map... ;(");
    }
```

Note: Also, I want it to work for all OS, which is why I am using OsUtils.isWindows() to modify the path.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you added your code using to get this folder? It's look like that you use String with wrong coding (for example use new String(utf8Bytes) instead of new String(utf8Bytes, "UTF8")) .

Comment: Probably an encoding issue in your code.

Comment: @ViacheslavVedenin Just added code

Comment: Problem with "saves/Pokémon Cobalt and Amethyst [DEMO]"? Can you try to check what encoding page for this java class file? UTF-8 or not?

Comment: @ViacheslavVedenin How do I know what encoding it's using?, should I change it to new String("saves/...", "UTF-8") ?

Comment: Can you check what encoding page for this java class file? In IDEA it's in the right-down corner of class window.

Comment: Can you try to replace "saves/Pokémon Cobalt and Amethyst [DEMO]"  to "saves/Pok" + '\u00e9' + mon Cobalt and Amethyst [DEMO]" ?

Comment: @ViacheslavVedenin Now it works, but I still get this error "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: character to be escaped is missing"

Comment: You could try NIO. It automatically does the path / vs \ stuff. It might fix the encoding problem as well, idk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix the problem! Thanks to everyone who helped me!

First of all, I had to replace "saves/Pokémon Cobalt and Amethyst [DEMO]" to "saves/Pok" + '\u00e9' + mon Cobalt and Amethyst [DEMO]" because of encoding issues.

Second of all, in my function that changes all "/"s to "\"s, I was using 
    return input.replaceAll("/", "\");
Changing it to 
    return input.replace("/", "\");
fixed the crash...